# How to add Product Version greater than 4 integer value in exe files?

Tags: python, versioning, nuitka

I am trying to add Product Version `2.1.1.122222` using nuitka command `nuitka --standalone .\newpyte.py --product-name="pname" --company-name="cname" --product-version="2.1.1.122222"`.

but facing an error: **FATAL: Error, product version must be a tuple of up to 4 integer values.**

Is there any way to add Product Version greater than 5 integer for exe/dll files?